# Why is the function $h(x)=f(x)-(\alpha x+\beta)$ the same as $f(x)$ in terms of continuity and differentiability?

Tags: calculus

Let $f:[a,b]\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function that is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$.

Consider the function $\mathcal{l}$ that passes through the points $(a,f(a))$ and $(b,f(b))$ given by:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{l}(x)=\alpha x+\beta, \quad\textrm{where}\hspace{3pt} \alpha=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}.
\end{equation}
Define $h(x)=f(x)-\mathcal{l}(x)$.

Why is the function $h$ continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$ just because $f$ is?

Comment: Because sum and product of differentiable functions is differentiable...and $\;l(x)\;$ is a polynomial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $\mathcal{l}(x)=\alpha x+\beta$ is continuous and differentiable, and the sum of two continuous (resp differentiable) functions is continuous (resp differentiable).